# Classification in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, classification, text-processing

I have these two classes

```
public class Iris_Setosa {

private double sepal_length;
private double sepal_width;
private double petal_length;
private double petal_width;


//Constractor
public Iris_Setosa(double s_length,double s_width,double p_length,double p_width)
{
    this.sepal_length=s_length;
    this.sepal_width=s_width;
    this.petal_length=p_length;
    this.petal_width=p_width;
}

public double sepal_length()
{
    return this.sepal_length;
}

public double sepal_width()
{
    return this.sepal_width;
}

public double petal_length()
{
    return this.petal_length;
}

public double petal_width()
{
    return this.petal_width;
}
}

public class Iris_Versicolour {
private double sepal_length;
private double sepal_width;
private double petal_length;
private double petal_width;


//Constractor
public Iris_Versicolour(double s_length,double s_width,double p_length,double p_width)
{
    this.sepal_length=s_length;
    this.sepal_width=s_width;
    this.petal_length=p_length;
    this.petal_width=p_width;

}


public double sepal_length()
{
    return this.sepal_length;
}

public double sepal_width()
{
    return this.sepal_width;
}

public double petal_length()
{
    return this.petal_length;
}

public double petal_width()
{
    return this.petal_width;
}
}
```

I defined two vectors and set data:

```
Vector <Iris_Setosa> I_Setosa = new Vector <Iris_Setosa>();
Vector <Iris_Versicolour> I_Versicolour = new Vector <Iris_Versicolouלr>();
//data
I_Setosa.add(new Iris_Setosa (4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3));
I_Setosa.add(new Iris_Setosa (5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4));
I_Versicolour.add(new Iris_Versicolour(6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5));
I_Versicolour.add(new Iris_Versicolour(6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5));
.......
```

How do we classify these two vectors together, in order to be treated as points in space?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: If you are trying to do a machine-learning task it would be more beneficial to put the data in a csv, with all the inputs and expected output. Then make objects to implement your machine learning method i.e. ANN, RBF, SVM etc. They will output a 0 or 1 depending on which flower it is. These machine learning problems aren't meant to be solved by representing every possible classification output as a class, imagine if it was a 20 class problem, you can't and shouldn't have to implement all those classes

Answer (score 0):

So now you have a new sample, **s** = [4.7, 3.3, 1.5, 0.5]

A first quick and dirty method would be 1NN (K Nearest Neighbors with K=1).  In this case you would compute the euclidean distance between **s** and each of your four points.
You would find that four your four cases you have the distances  5.93, 6.40, 6.94, and 7.12.  In this case you choose the first training sample since it is closest, leading to a prediction of I_Setosa.  More specifically, it was most similar to Iris_Setosa (4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3)

Hope this helps